# SharedPreferences returning wrong value and not updating current values

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I created a simple code to test SharedPreferences feature on android. First initializes the SharedPreferences' instance and the value of the boolean var is retrieved from it, using 'false' as default value and then it's set to 'true'. When onStop is called the value is stored in SharedPreferences as 'true', when onDestroy is called the key-value pair is removed. But what it happens is that the value is 'true' before it's set in the onCreate method, while it should be 'false' and then 'true'.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences preferences;
    private String KEY = "PREF_KEY";
    private String PREFS = "my_preferences";
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    boolean value;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);

        value = preferences.getBoolean(KEY, false);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: BEFORE " + value);
        value = true;
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: AFTER " + value);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        preferences.edit().putBoolean(KEY, value).apply();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        preferences.edit().clear().apply();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the behaviour you are expecting you need to put `super.onStop();` **after** `preferences.edit().putBoolean(KEY, value).apply();` in `onStop()`, like so:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
  preferences.edit().putBoolean(KEY, value).apply();
  super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: I tried but I don't know why after the call to onDestroy the value is not deleted and when I reopen the app the value is 'true' again, even if it should be 'false' at the beginning.

Comment: @FrancescoGreco Make sure the `onStop` and `onDestroy` methods are being called when you expect by putting print statements in them.